# py -2 pointing to Python 3.x path and returning syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Installed both Python 3.6 and 2.7 on my Win10 system, on trying to use the Python launcher for 2.7 I get the following error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>py -2
  File "C:\Python36-32\Lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Relevant environment variables are:

- **PATH** - Python3.6; Python3.6\Scripts\
- **PYTHONHOME** - Python3.6
- **PYTHONPATH** - Python3.6\Lib

---

What do I need to do to get the Python launcher to work with Python 2.7

Comment: What's the python launcher? Normally the command is `python` or `python2` or `python3`. I've never seen `py -2`. By the looks of it you're trying to run python 2 but all your paths point to python 3 files which will of course fail. Have you considered using a virtual environment?

Comment: what is `py -2`?

Comment: miniconda or Anaconda is better tool to manage multiple virtualenv

Comment: `py` is a Windows wrapper to work around some of the idiocies of that particular platform.

Comment: [This](https://blog.python.org/2011/07/python-launcher-for-windows_11.html) is `py`

Comment: @triplee. Doesn't seem to be doing too good of a job in this instance :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\python27\python.exe" yourscript.py` .